# Virtual Box - Windows key flipped with LCTRL on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, sharpkeys

Please help. My Windows VM on Linux host (VirtualBox) has the "**LCTRL**" and "**Windows special key**" flipped, so that all apps like VS and IntelliJ IDEA treat the Windows special key as CTRL.

Even when copying, I have to use "**Windows+C**" and "**Windows+V**", which is hightly problematic.
With [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys), I tried to flip it back, but that doesnt do anything. The only solution using SharpKeys is to disable the Windows button and add LCTRL  as Windows (which is treated as LCTRL by the VM).

So is VirtualBox treating my keyboard layout as a MAC keyboard?

Comment: So is virtual box treating my keyboard layout as MAC keyboard?

Comment: Hint: you can add to the question by [edit]ing, instead of writing comments.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed VirtualBox guest additions, and the problem subsided.